# Best way to find a single record using ActiveRecord 3 / Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Where I used to do this:

```
Foo.find_by_bar('a-value')
```

I can now do this:

```
Foo.where(:bar => 'a-value').limit(1).first
```

Is this recommended? Is this the best way? Should I continue to use the "old" way because it continues to be useful syntactic sugar, or is there an Even Better way I can do that now, which will support chaining and all the other good stuff?

Comment: I actually quite like the old find_by_*. The intent is clear, and if that's all you need, the syntax is simpler.

Comment: And its still perfectly valid in Rails 3. If using Rails 4, you can use `find_by(bar: 'a-value')`.

Comment: I came here looking for _just_ a single record. If anyone else is after the same, I've popped an answer to this scenario [down here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326440/best-way-to-find-a-single-record-using-activerecord-3-arel/66600205#answer-66600205) :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Rails 4 :

```
Foo.find_by( bar: 'a_value', wibble: 'a wibble value' )
```

Comment: Can you add a source for this?

Comment: Any idea why RubyMine warns that this method should not be called from view helper?

Comment: find_by is kind of a heavy operation and its advisable not to trigger while rendering view

Answer (score 26):

I think the preferable way to return a single record would be along the lines of your second example, but you can omit the limit part:

```
Foo.where(:bar => 'a-value').first
```

This follows the new syntax and supports chaining if you want to add more conditions to the lookup.

Comment: Use `Foo.where(:bar => 'a-value').first!` if you want to ensure a record is found. That way `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will be raised otherwise.

Comment: Rails adds `ORDER BY "foo"."id" ASC` in this case. It can make the query less efficient.

Answer (score 7):

If you need one and only one record (which I came here looking for), Rails 7.0 introduces [`find_sole_by`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_sole_by) (or `where(...).sole`) for this.

The behaviour is as follows:

> Finds the sole matching record. Raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record is found. Raises `ActiveRecord::SoleRecordExceeded` if more than one record is found.

Use case is simple:

```
Foo.find_sole_by(bar: 'a-value')
```

Handy for those occasions where a single record is mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

Rails gives you a whole load of magic methods for this kind of thing:

```
Foo.find_by_bar('a-value')
```

You can also use multiple attributes:

```
Foo.find_by_bar_and_wibble('a foo value', 'a wibble value')
```

And appending a ! causes it to throw a RecordNotFound if nothing's found:

```
Foo.find_by_bar!('a-value')
```

Comment: These dynamic finders are deprecated as of rails 4.0 (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) so it's probably not a good habit to learn now.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative:

```
Foo.find(:first, conditions: { bar: 'a-value' })
```

You can also use multiple attributes:

```
Foo.find(:first, conditions: { bar: 'a-value' , wibble: 'a wibble value' })
```