# Rails migration script changes does not persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wrote a migration script to update all previous records in ActiveRecord.

```
class UpdateListCompletedAtFields < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
    Car.find_each do |car|
        if car.list_car_step_3_finished?
            car.list_completed_at = Time.now
            puts "Car #{car.id} list_completed, updating list_completed_at: #{car.list_completed_at}"
        end
    end
  end

end
```

when I run the migration script, the puts message output the field car.list_completed_at correctly, but when I then get into rails console (after I extied) and try to check the data, the migration did not persist. I am wondering if I am missing anything?

```
Car.all.map{|m| [m.list_car_step_3_finished, m.list_completed_at]}
=>[[true, nil], [true, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil], [true, nil], [nil, nil]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to save `car` record:

```
car.list_completed_at = Time.now
car.save
# (...)
```

Comment: Hi.I'm actually wondering why you deleted your answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629261/retrieving-a-single-record-from-an-activerecord-rails-query/22630078#22630078 though its correct and you are the first person who answered.Forgive me if its not the correct way to communicate with you.

Comment: @Pavan I din't read the question carefully, so my answer was simply incorrect.

Comment: But your answer is right and see the remaining answers.those all eually same as your answer.

Comment: Yeah! you are right.But according to the title of the question,your answer and those remaining all are right! Except that exception part where the OP asked 'if there is more than 1' :)

Answer (score 0):

Use update_attribute to update the database

```
if car.list_car_step_3_finished?
   car.update_attribute(:list_completed_at, Time.now)
   puts "Car #{car.id} list_completed, updating list_completed_at:#car.list_completed_at}"
end
```